# splitting long string at indices in parallel in python

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have many files that each have several million rows; each row is a dumped data entry and is several hundred characters long. The rows come in groups and the first two characters tell me the type of row it is, and I use that to parse it. This structure prohibits me from loading the rows to a dataframe, for example, or anything else that does not go through the rows one at a time.

For each row, I currently create a dictionary vals = {}, and then sequentially run through about fifty keys along the lines of

vals{'name'} = row[2:24]

vals{'state'} = row[24:26]

Instead of doing fifty assignments sequentially, can I do this simultaneously or in parallel in some simple manner?

Is

vals{'name'},vals{'state'} = row[2:24],row[24:26]

faster if I do this simultaneous assignment for many entries? I could also reformulate this as a list comprehension. Would that be faster than running through sequentially?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, no, doing multiple assignment will not speed up your program. This is because the multiple assignment syntax is just a different way of writing multiple assignments on different lines.

For example

```
vals{'name'},vals{'state'} = row[2:24],row[24:26]
```

is equivalent to

```
vals{'name'}= row[2:24]
vals{'state'} = row[2:24]
```

If you want to optimize your code, your should start by [profiling it](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/profile.html) to determine the parts that are taking the largest amount of time. I would also check to ensure that you are not doing multiple reads from the same file, as these are very slow compared to reading from memory. If possible, you should [read the entire file into memory](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) first, and then process it.